# MySQL syntax error says "near '1'" but I don't have a '1' in my query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a website for the first time using PHP with a MySQL database and getting a syntax error that I don't understand. I just want to delete everything from `tblreparation` with a certain `ID` and also everything from `rblrepstat` with that same `ID`. I am using this code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","MYPASS","repair");
    $ID = $_REQUEST['ID'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM tblreparation WHERE ID = {$ID}");
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM tblrepstat WHERE repID = {$ID}");
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error2: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record deleted";
    mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

And this is the error I am getting:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1

Near 1? I don't even see a '1'...

Comment: `{$ID}` remove `{}` and `$ID = intval($_REQUEST['ID']);` if it is an integer.

Comment: instead of `{$ID}` use `'$ID'`

Comment: tnx for the fast answer but it is still the same..

Comment: @Cheery: `{$foo}` is perfectly valid PHP. That's not the problem.

Comment: @ivancoene show the result of `echo "DELETE FROM tblreparation WHERE ID = $ID";` ... `That's not the problem` but not necessary here.

Comment: @Cheery DELETE FROM tblreparation WHERE ID = 27 it seems normal...

Comment: @ivancoene: Does that particular query produce the error?  Or is there a different value of `$ID` which produces the error?

Comment: @David it's the query i guess.. i tried it with different ID's but ist always the same..

Comment: @ivancoene did try to retype it? may be you have some unicode unprintable characters there. The query is ok. And did you try to use `intval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling mysqli_query twice for each query.

The second time you call it you're actually passing a resource as the query parameter, which causes the error you're getting.

Try changing your code to this:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","MYPASS","repair");
    $ID = $_REQUEST['ID'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tblreparation WHERE ID = {$ID}";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tblrepstat WHERE repID = {$ID}";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error2: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record deleted";
    mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `$ID` might contain 1. Which also the location of the error in the query.

```
DELETE FROM tblreparation WHERE ID = $ID
```

Or **if** ID is containing a string or stored in another format which is string related (varchar) then wrap it in quotes:

```
DELETE FROM tblreparation WHERE ID = '$ID'
```

Comment: @ivancoene Can you update your question to show the contents and var_dump of `$_REQUEST['ID'];`